# How to control vertical spacing of footnotes with footmisc package

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I am using the footmisc package with the side and flushmargin options.  When two footnotes appear in the text on two consecutive sentences the footnotes themselves overlap.  Is there an option to adjust the distance between them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I cook up a simple document with two sentences and long footnotes in the margin, they  do not overlap. Please post some code, that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The issue mysteriously resolved.  I changed some options in both the footmisc and  geometry package, so that may have done it.